# What are the major differences between solr modules

Tags: 7, search

I am looking into Solr search for my site and am seeing two equally well-used modules.

- [Apache Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) (lots of contrib around this)
- [Search API Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr), built on Search API

Why would I pick one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using Search Api Solr. Search Api Solr is a little bit more complex; however, it is more powerful.  In addition there are many sub-modules that allow you to extended the search funcionality.

You should consider reading the article [Battleplan for Search & Solr in Drupal 8](https://www.acquia.com/blog/battleplan-search-solr-drupal-8).

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631327/how-can-i-integrate-the-apache-solr-search-with-my-drupal-7-site).

> The two maintainers of Search API and Apache Solr have meet in person and have determined a way forward for advanced searches with Drupal and they both have agreed that Search API is it.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the modules deliver the same base functionality but search api solr came later and is now well maintained widely supported. It integrates better because it has all the support from search api. 
The Solr is only a backend. That is why with search api you can extend almost endlessly. I would also propose to not use an external backend at all. 
Just search api with database backend would do just fine when you have not more then a 1000 nodes.
The database backend also supports facets like Solr does.

Comment: Faceting with SQL is quite resource intensive and Drupal's SQL based search is fairly porr in general. It is ok for small sites as you say but I would generally recommend solr over SQL search every time if it is an available option. It means you are hitting your drupal database much less (unless search isn't really being used much anyway).

Answer (score 2):

I have made a few sites with each solution and have done some custom work also with both and I would be happy to recommend either solution.

Initially there were differences between them that made it more easy to decide which would be better for you based on your requirements (like non-node entity searching or support for certain add-on modules) but these days they are very similar as others have said.

If you have very basic requirements you can really pick either.

If you have specific performance concerns then you would be best to try both options and benchmark them for speed with your particular setup to know which performs better and is it by enough that it matters.

If you require specific add-on functionality then investigate what is available for each and see how well those add-ons are maintained etc. and that can sometimes help you decide.

The other thing if you have time is to try them both out and see which you find better to use. If you don't have much in the way of complex requirements then usability may be the deciding factor.

There are still some example use cases where one seems to be clearly better than the other however those are getting less common and more niche.

It really depends on your specific requirements and your personal preference (which can be determined by trying them both out).

Since they are joining forces for Drupal 8 I would expect an upgrade path from both Drupal 7 options to the new Drupal 8 option.